# How to register a record in Route53 of another account with serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, amazon-route53

I want to register CloudFornt records in another account using serverless framework, but I'm wondering how this can be achieved.

Currently, we are operating AWS with multiple accounts, so it is essential to register records of another account on the main Route53.

Is there any way?
Please let me know if there are any useful articles.

Comment: You can forward / delegate route53 between different accounts, e.g. https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/share-route-53-domains-across-aws-accounts.html

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.